# How do I convert this Northwind automapper code from C# to VB

Tags: vb.net

I have this code:

```
using AutoMapper;

namespace Northwind.Application.Common.Mappings
{
    public interface IMapFrom<T>
    {   
        void Mapping(Profile profile) => profile.CreateMap(typeof(T), GetType());
    }
}
```

... that I need to convert to vb.

I've tried something like this:

```
Imports AutoMapper

Public Interface IMapFrom(Of T)

    Public Property Mapping(profile As Profile) = CType(Profile.CreateMap(TypeOf (T), GetType()) As profile)

End Interface
```

... but that is not correct.

What is the correct vb code?

Thanks.

Comment: The C# code is declaring a method, so of course VB code that declares a property is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalent.  The C# uses a new feature called "default interface methods" (in this case, an "expression-bodied default interface method").  This is one of many new C# features that aren't being replicated in VB. (Also, as jmcilhinney pointed out, the C# code uses a method, not a property).

Default interface methods can be called on any object of the interface type - meaning an interface can now specify behavior and is not strictly what we've come to know as an 'interface' any longer (hooray if you like complexity - gotta give language designers something to do).

Comment: I don't know for sure but I'm guessing that this feature is a response to complaints by devs. If you have an interface that needs to be implemented in multiple classes and many/most of the members will be implemented in the same way in each class then this may be a boon. A common base class could be an alternative but not if some other base class is already being used.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: Sure, but language designers should realize that there's a tradeoff.  C# is getting new features at the drop of a hat that have marginal value (tuples - instead of just defining a small class, local functions - don't get me started).  Once C# is as complex as C++, it'll lead to a mass migration from C# to newer 'simpler' languages and it'll start all over again.